# How do make my bot send message without an update?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

i am creating a telegram bot in java bot but i have problem,I have seen bots that send text\ad without an update from a user ,I want to know how i can do it .It is only sending messages when the user sends a message to it.i need to know how can i make my bot send some message without a onUpdateReceived.(sorry for my english)

onUpdateReceived(Update update) only sends message when the user sends a command

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`onUpdateReceived(Update)` is just a method called when you bot gets an update, but it is not the only place where your bot can call `execute(SendMessage)`.
What you need is to write a method in your bot like

```
public void sendAds() {
    for (Integer chatId: usersYouWantToPing) {
        SendMessage ad = new SendMessage
            .setChatId(chatId)
            .setText(text);
        execute(ad);
    }
}
```

obviously since you have no `User` sender object you have to find a criteria to who send the message (maybe you want to store the ids of the users you want to ping in a DB).

The issue now is: how do you trigger this method? The answer is: however you want.

One way could be to schedule some **cron jobs** to periodically execute `sendAds()`. To do so you could define it in the `main` method, right after you register your bot. Using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) lib you can write something like

```
    /* Instantiate the job that will call the bot function */
    JobDetail jobSendAd = JobBuilder.newJob(SendAd.class)
        .withIdentity("sendAd")
        .build();

    /* Define a trigger for the call */
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("everyMorningAt8")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(8, 0))
        .build();

    /* Create a scheduler to manage triggers */
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.getContext().put("bot", bot);
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobSendAd, trigger);
```

Where `SendAd` is an implementation of `Job` interface that actually calls the bot method, like

```
public class SendNotification implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        schedulerContext = jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getContext();
        YourBot bot = (YourBot) schedulerContext.get("bot");
        bot.sendNotification();
    }
}
```

For further details I suggest you to check my [telegram bot template](https://github.com/aSlug/TelegramBot) that provide this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of Send message.
Eg.

```
SendMessage message = new SendMessage (chatid,text)
```

And then just let execute the instance with your bot.

```
SendMessage message = new SendMessage (chatid,text)
bot.execute(message)
```

Obviously the chatid camp should be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

This tricky way worked for me.

Telegram bot needs to know **chatID** of that certain group or personal chat that bot talks with.

First you have to get chatId which is **Long**.

Create /chatid command with help of BotFather in telegram.

And use that command in java like this:

```
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    public Long chatId = null;

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

        String input = update.getMessage().getText();
        SendMessage output = new SendMessage();

        if (input.equals("/chatid")) {
            chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
            System.out.println("chatId = " + chatId);
            output.setText("chatid is  = " + chatId);
        }

        output.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId());
        try {
            execute(output);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void sayImNotRobot() {
    SendMessage message = new SendMessage();

    message.enableMarkdown(true);
    message.setChatId((long) chatIdLike123456); //Write chatID manually here
    message.setText("Im not robot");
    try {
        execute(message);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
    
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "your bot name here";
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "your bot token here";
    }
}
```

In main class use that method to print chatId to console and copy paste it (from console result) to chatIdLike123456 that i wrote in TelegramBot class.

```
 public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApiContextInitializer.init();
            TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
            try {
                telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramBot());
                TelegramBot bot = new TelegramBot();
                bot.sayImNotRobot(); //now, you can call this method whenever you want
 
  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is possible only by using the `Random` Java class or if you know the user chat id.

I think that Telegram bots with ads work this way.